# heroku: flush redis in release phase

Tags: heroku, redis, release, heroku-ci

I have a node app running on heroku and I'm trying to use the release phase to flush my redis cache on deploy.

I've added the `release: ./release-tasks.sh` to my `Procfile` but I'm having a hard time finding information what tools are available for me to use in the release phase.

Currently my `release-tasks.sh` file looks like this:

```
redis-cli -u $REDIS_URL flushall
```

But it errors out with a `redis-cli not found` and it cannot find the `heroku` command either.

It says in the release-phase docs that it is a good place to invalidate a cache, does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: 1. heroku redis:cli -a my_app --confirm my_app
2. FLUSHALL

- found at https://menubar.io/heroku-redis-flushall

Answer (score 0):

`redis-cli` nor the Heroku CLI is available on a dyno so you can't use them here. Depending on the language your app is built in your could write a task in that language that flushes the cache and then invoke that task from your shell script.

Comment: I suspected something like this might be the way to go, I'll give it a go next week and report back. Thanks for response!